# Trying to connect to Isilon Server

Tags: network-share, isilon

I currently have an issue trying to connect 2 64bit Windows machines to an Isilon file server.  I am able to ping the server as well as get to the admin web page of the Isilon, however I cannot access any of the shares.  All other machines in the building are able to access the server fine, except these 2 machines.  I have no experience with Isilon and no access to the Isilon server as they are actually maintained by a different organization within my building which does not like talking to me about this issue, so I am looking for any information that could help figure out the cause of why 2 machines cannot connect to the shares on this Isilon server.

Comment: Are there other 64bit Windows machines connected to the Isilon?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what OS?  64Bit Windows narrows this down to about half a dozen possibilities.

Comment: Without access to the system can you even be sure that there is nothing wrong with permissions or samba (ie if other users are not using windows).

Answer (score 0):

Assumming you are talking about CIFS access to the Isilon, you're going to have to check with the Isilon administrator to ensure that access has been granted to the two systems you are having problems with.  They may have been left off for some reason.